# Preventing Div Elements From Wrapping in a Fluid Navigation

Tags: css, uinavigationbar

- I have a top nav that extends across the page
- Within that top nav I have various elements

  - two that must align left
  - one that must align right
- The nav is fluid the elements are fixed widths
- Do not want the elements to wrap when the browser window is minimized
- Needs to work in IE6 on up due to high Chinese audience.

See example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/4SUwg/

```
<div id="header">
  <div id="headerContent">
    <div class="search-list"> Search List </div>
    <div class="social-buttons"> Social </div>
    <div class="signin"> Login Drop Down </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like the div elements within the nav to not wrap. I searched around on stack and could find answers that come close but nothing that completely addressed the issue. My need to have the div element aligned right complicates matters. Must work in all browsers, especially IE's.

Thanks all for your help in advance!!!

Comment: If it's a fluid layout then you shouldn't have given a definite width to `.search-list` and two other divs in headerContent.

Comment: Hi Deepak, the nav is fluid across the page but the nav elements are fixed widths. Two aligned left and one that needs to align right. I updated the question, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works in all browsers, specifically IE6 on up since that was a requirement for this project. If you have something better that accomplishes the same thing please post! My sincere thanks to everyone who answered/helped.

```
<div id="header2">
    <table id="headerContent2">
        <tr>
            <td id="left" valign="top">
                <div id="leftWrapper">
                <div class="search-list2">Search List</div>
                <div class="social-buttons2">Social Buttons</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td id="middle">&nbsp;</td>
            <td id="right" valign="top">
                <div class="signin2">Login Drop Down</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>


<style>
#header2 {
background: #404040;
height: 35px;
color: white;
margin: 0 0 12px 0;
}

#headerContent2 {
width:100%;
}

#headerContent2 td {
height: 32px;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

.search-list2 { 
width:150px; 
float:left;
background:#039;
}

.social-buttons2 { 
width:200px; 
float:left;
background:#060;
}

.signin2 { 
background:#F00;
float:right;
width:400px;
}

#leftWrapper {
width:400px;    
}

#middle {
width:100%;
}
</style>
```

See Demo of it working here. Copy the code and try it out in all the IE's since JSfiddle does not work in all IE's.
http://jsfiddle.net/GtXKE/

Answer (score 0):

Use SPAN ..  It's INLINE and not BLOCK ??

```
<div id="header">
  <div id="headerContent">
     <span class="search-list"> Search List </span>
     <span class="social-buttons"> Social </span>
     <span class="signin"> Login Drop Down </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And your CSS, remove floats

```
<style>
body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#header {
background: #404040;
height: 35px;
color: white;
margin: 0 0 12px 0;
overflow-x:auto; overflow-y:hidden;
}

#headerContent {
height: 32px;
border:1px dashed #fff;
}

.search-list {
width:150px;

background:#039;
}

.social-buttons {
width:150px;

background:#060;
}

.signin {
width:200px;

background:#F00;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Zak! Can you include a JSfiddle link with your example please? Also I updated the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You want a fluid layout but the most important rule of a fluid layout is not to set a definite width of elements but you have set the width.

The CSS have a `<style>` tag, which is not required, probably you put it by mistake.

I have set the width of divs inside headerContent in percentage value. The CSS is

```
body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#header {
background: #404040;
height: 35px;
color: white;
margin: 0 0 12px 0;
overflow-x:auto; overflow-y:hidden; 
}

#headerContent {
height: 32px;
border:1px dashed #fff;
}

.search-list { 
width:28%; 
float:left;
background:#039;
}

.social-buttons { 
width:28%; 
float:left;
background:#060;
}

.signin { 
width:28%; 
float:right;
background:#F00; 
}
```

Just changed the width value and on my browser it looked fine, better than the before version. Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DeepakKamat/s52Hn/8/

Comment: Thanks for your answer Deepak! My goal is to have fixed width nav elements but a fluid outer nav. I updated my question and example.

Comment: Then you must try media queries to apply a different style for the elements inside the headerContent in different screen sizes.   
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Thanks, I'm hoping to find a solution without using media queries. I will keep testing some things out and post my answer here.